# Trigger to insert multiple rows based on many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have three tables `Reservation`, `Reservation_Passenger` and `Ticket`.

Each reservation can have multiple passengers. I need to create a trigger to insert a ticket (according to the number of passengers) every time the Reservation status is updated to 'Booked'. How can I achieve it?

- Reservation (reservationId, status)
- Reservation_Passenger (reservationId, passengerId)
- Ticket (ticketId, passengerId, issuedDate)

What I have tried:

```
CREATE 
    TRIGGER Generate_Ticket 
    ON Reservation
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @reservationStatus varchar(15)

    SELECT @reservationStatus =  INSERTED.Status from INSERTED

    IF @reservationStatus = 'Booked'
        BEGIN
        --stuck here

        END
GO
```

Comment: You have to use the CREATE TRIGGER command. What have you tried so far and where did you get blocked ?.

Comment: Please post your existing attempt and and explain what is not working or where you are stuck. [Trigger tutorial](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/)

Comment: @MarcGuillot I have updated my post

Comment: @Stu  I have updated my post

Comment: Please have a read through [this article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you store the status into a variable, you could also retrieve the reservationId

```
DECLARE @reservationStatus varchar(15)
DECLARE @reservationId int

SELECT @reservationId = INSERTED.reservationId, 
       @reservationStatus = INSERTED.Status 
FROM INSERTED
```

Now in the part where you are stuck, to create a Ticket to every passenger on the reservation you can feed an INSERT with a SELECT of the related passengers.

```
INSERT INTO Ticket (passengerId, issuedDate)
       SELECT passengerId, getdate()
       FROM Reservation_Passenger
       WHERE reservationId = @reservationId
```

**PS** You will need to be careful that your code doesn't change more than one reservation to booked on the same UPDATE command. Because in that case the trigger is only fired once, with all the updated reservations stored in the INSERTED dataset. You will need to use a CURSOR to loop through all those reservations to apply your logic, or switch to this simpler trigger that creates tickets for all the passengers of all the booked reservations in one single step:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Generate_Ticket ON Reservation AFTER UPDATE
AS

INSERT INTO Ticket (passengerId, issuedDate)
       SELECT P.passengerId, getdate()
       FROM INSERTED as R
            INNER JOIN Reservation_Passenger as P on P.reservationId = R.reservationID
       WHERE R.Status = 'Booked'
```

You should also be careful because the trigger fires when any field is updated on the Reservation table. If you were to update another field, for example a comment, on an already booked reservation, your trigger will duplicate all his tickets again.

I recommend you to check not only that INSERTED.Status = 'Booked', but also that DELETED.Status <> 'Booked', so you only create tickets when the Status field has changed to Booked from something else.

That would be :

```
CREATE TRIGGER Generate_Ticket ON Reservation AFTER UPDATE
AS

INSERT INTO Ticket (passengerId, issuedDate)
       SELECT P.passengerId, getdate()
       FROM INSERTED as I
            INNER JOIN DELETED as D on D.reservationId = I.reservationID
            INNER JOIN Reservation_Passenger as P on P.reservationId = I.reservationID
       WHERE I.Status = 'Booked' and coalesce(D.Status, '') <> 'Booked'
```

Comment: This has the same bug I linked to in the above comments and assumes only 1 row will ever be updated.

Comment: @Stu I was adding an addendum with some of the problems of his logic and how to solve them.